# Rabbitmq listener not connecting to another machine

Tags: sockets, ubuntu, ssl, rabbitmq

I successfully ran an example from the [rabbitmq-c](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c) library on my virtual machine (runnung Ubuntu). Now, when I try to run the example on another device (say Device 2), which is trying to listen to messages sent by my virtual machine (with rabbit server running on the virtual machine), I get the following error:

> $ ./amqp_listen VM_IP_address 5672 amq.direct test
>   $ Logging in: connection closed unexpectedly

which is the result of the following operation in amqp_listen.c:

```
die_on_amqp_error(amqp_login(conn, "/", 0, 131072, 0, AMQP_SASL_METHOD_PLAIN, "guest", "guest"),
                    "Logging in");
```

I noticed that if I run this command on Device 2, I see this message:

> $ telnet VM_IP_address 5672
>   $ Connection closed by foreign host

I'm not an expert, but I guess there must be some networking configuration settings that prevent the Ubuntu VM to accepting incoming connections. But I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: You're missing the ip address at the telnet line. If you add it, will you get the same error?

Comment: Yes, same error. updating the question.

Comment: What kind of VM do you use? Networking settings?

Answer (score 0):

I've just stumbled on this question, I see it's an old one but I'll give it a go :)
Quoting [rabbitmq docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html):

> "guest" user can only connect via localhost By default, the guest user
>   is prohibited from connecting to the broker remotely; it can only
>   connect over a loopback interface (i.e. localhost).

And how to make it work:

> If you wish to allow the guest user to connect from a remote host, you
>   should set the loopback_users configuration item to []. A complete
>   rabbitmq.config which does this would look like:
>
> [{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].